# Rolling count in pandas 0.18.0 with time slices

Tags: python, pandas

Data is a df with a time series index with 50MM rows. Using pandas 0.18.0, where rolling with a time delta window is not implemented, is there a way to rewrite this to make it faster?

```
data.index.map(lambda x: data.loc[x-pd.Timedelta(hours=1):x,'people'].count())
```

Data looks like:

```
data.loc[:5,'people']

09/15/2017 10:00:01.123456    3
09/15/2017 10:00:01.512345    5
09/15/2017 10:00:03.010101    10
09/15/2017 12:00:10.989898    2
09/15/2017 14:00:00.000000    4
```

Comment: What's the raw data look like? Sometimes I find the easiest way to get massive performance improvements is to parse the data yourself and use something like cython or numba to get fast and efficient loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I've had a lot of success with numba in the past. There are options to pre-compile which you can look up on the official documentation which would eliminate the delay associated with compiling on the first loop iteration every time. You can also use `cache=True` as a keyword in the `jit()` decorator to save the compiled version between runs.

Rolling window functions are relatively straightforward and lend themselves to the fast loop iteration possible with compiled code. This function should give the rolling total of "people" over a window less than or equal to one hour wide (3600.0 seconds). The inputs are given as numpy arrays with "time" being of `dtype=np.float64` and comprised of unix timestamps in seconds from epoch. "people" again is an array of `dtype=np.int32`

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

@jit("i4[:](f8[:], i4[:], f8)") #returns a 32 bit int array with inputs: (64 bit float array, 32 bit int array, 64 bit float)
def rolling_sum(time, people, width=3600.0):
    #assuming time is sorted..
    left = 0 #left side of the window
    out = np.empty_like(time)
    running_sum = people[0]
    out[0] = running_sum #first entry

    for right in range(1,len(time)): #right side of the window
        #add next value from "people" to running sum
        running_sum += people[right]

        #move left edge to the right until window is less or equal to "width" seconds wide
        while time[right] - time[left] >= width:
            #subtract from running sum what's no longer in the window
            running_sum -= people[left]
            #shrink the window
            left += 1
        #record running sum at window position
        out[right] = running_sum
    return out
```

#### Edit:

A rolling count is even easier than a rolling sum:

```
@jit("i4[:](f8[:], f8)")
def rolling_count(time, width=3600.0):
    left = 0 
    out = np.empty_like(time)
    out[0] = 1
    for right in range(1,len(time)):
        while time[right] - time[left] >= width:
            left += 1
        out[right] = right - left + 1 #addition of 1 accounts for inclusive range
    return out
```

The precision of the timestamps in the original dataset will dictate the accuracy of the count. I wrote the function to use 64bit floating point numbers as the timestamps, which guarantees (until additional computation is done) 15 significant figures in base 10. The current time on my machine (`time.time()`) reads: 1505505879.4849467 (EDT: UTC - 4) however only 1505505879.48494 can be considered accurate according to floating point precision, and likely even less considering the update frequency of the system clock by the operating system.

Comment: Looks like this is a running sum, the question is simply looking for a running count. the only changes then would be to set people[right] and people[left] to 1s right? Also, will this work for millisecond precision?

Comment: @user4446237 yes a running count should be even easier. Precision will depend on how accurate the timestamps were taken. This function itself is only limited by the precision of the floating point value you give it. The actual precision of any calls to time (for any language) will depend on the operating system. Many only update the system clock every second or at most 50-100 time per second. python will generally try to use the most accurate source for `time.time()` and will always return a float, which may indicate more precision than is actually possible.